# Using wildcards in boto3 get_policy_versions

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

Simple question I am hoping someone can answer cause I have had a hard time finding the answer on the aws documentation. Furthermore this is not something I can test immediately or I would have and spared everyone this question. I have a scenario where I need to generate the arn for policies by constructing them. In the case of the arn and policy name some of the arn's have paths before the name.

> :resource/path/name_of_policy

others just have

> :resource/name_of_policy

I could get them from another boto3 call but my time complexity would double and I would like to keep it as simple as efficient as possible.

my question here is will the following code handle if a path does or does not exist in the arn?

```
arn = 'arn:aws:iam::{}:policy/*{}'.format(account_id, p)
versions = iam.list_policy_versions(PolicyArn=arn)['Versions']
```

AWS is finicky with where wildcards are placed and being relatively new to working with AWS programmatically I was hoping someone with more experience could answer this one.

I suspect this will work but I would like some confirmation.

Comment: You can try it, but I doubt it will work, because the underlying [ListPolicyVersions API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListPolicyVersions.html) *"Lists information about the versions of the specified managed policy, including the version that is currently set as the policy's default version."* This is singular. It also does not appear to return an ARN with each policy version returned, so the response object has no capability of telling you what you matched. These points imply that no wildcard is appropriate in the request, since that could mean more than one match.

Comment: i will update my question when I am able to run it and know for sure. however after your explenation i think you are right. this will fail which means i need to redo my logic again which is not horrible but it will mean the time complexity will double.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you were right. i posted the results of the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering my own question here:** 
Using the method i asked about in the original post will yield the following exception.

> An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the ListPolicyVersions
>   operation: ARN arn:aws:iam::YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID:policy/*YOUR_POLICY_NAME is
>   not valid.

In short this is not a valid way of getting listed policy versions. I will need to pull in everything the old fashioned way.